# How should I deal with a \n printed by `with-out-str` at the end of the output in a Clojure test?

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a test to check if the output printed to the console matches the JSON string I expect.

```
(deftest create-account-test
  (testing "Create account"
    (is (= (str (cheshire/generate-string {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}))
           (with-out-str
             (io/-main "test/sample-input.txt"))))))
```

The test breaks due to a mismatch: the `\n` that comes at the end of the actual output:

```
actual: "{\"account\":{\"active-card\":true,\"available-limit\":100},\"violations\":[]}\n"          
diff: - "{\"account\":{\"active-card\":true,\"available-limit\":100},\"violations\":[]}"          
      + "{\"account\":{\"active-card\":true,\"available-limit\":100},\"violations\":[]}\n"
```

How should I deal with this newline at the end?

I considered concatenating a `\newline` with the expected string, but I guess there's a better solution.

Comment: Trim? Add the line break to the expected output? If the way you are running your tests influences the result then compensate in the test. Especially if it has no relevance for SUT (line breaks, petty prining, key-order, ...)

Comment: If the intent of the test is check for equivalence of the JSON with a regular _unordered_ map, then a naive string comparison is flawed. Consider if the expected string was `"{\"a\":0,\"b\":1}"` but the actual string was `"{\"b\":1,\"a\":0}"`, or `"{\"a\" : 0, \"b\" : 1}"`. Would you consider that to be a pass or fail?

Comment: Why do you think the expected string _shouldn't_ contain a trailing newline?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```clj
(deftest create-account-test
  (testing "Create account"
    (is (= {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}
           (-> (with-out-str (io/-main "test/sample-input.txt"))
               json/read-string))))))
```

but if you have a good reason to compare strings, simply add a \n into it.

```clj
(deftest create-account-test
  (testing "Create account"
    (is (= (str (cheshire/generate-string {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}) "\n")
           (with-out-str
             (io/-main "test/sample-input.txt"))))))
```